# Use CNPhoneNumber into UIPasteboard

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to take the number from any contact that the user pick, then copy it inside pasteboard, so here is my code:

```
import Contacts
import ContactsUI
```

the in the button:

```
@IBAction func callMe(_ sender: UIButton) {




    let cnPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    cnPicker.delegate = self
    self.present(cnPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)



    func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact]){
        contacts.forEach { contact in
            for number in contact.phoneNumbers {
                let phoneNumber = number.value 
                print("number is = \(phoneNumber)")

                let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
                pasteboard.string = "\("*199*"+phoneNumber+"#")"



            }
        }
    }
```

so I had the ERROR:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'CNPhoneNumber'

I think it's an easy tip but I couldn't reach it, I'll be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply the string interpolation only to phoneNumber so it's converted from CNPhoneNumber to String.

```
pasteboard.string = "*199*\(phoneNumber)#"
```